# Protractor with Jasmine2 - How to exit spec early for some expectations, but not all?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a suite that contains a number of specs. Each spec contains calls to a number of reusable functions (shared across specs and suites). Some of those functions include expectations, some don't. Effectively, these functions create "building blocks" from which my specs, and suites are built.

Currently, when I run my tests, they continue "relentlessly" - ie, if an expectation fails, the test does its best to continue. And that is, for the most part absolutely fine.

However, I have one or two reusable functions which include expectations that if they fail, all remaining function calls / expectations in that spec are guaranteed to fail - and as such there is no point continuing - better to abort that spec, and try the next one in the suite.

But I cannot see any way this can be done - googling etc has only suggested "bail on first fail" type options, which isn't the same thing.

Obviously (unless I'm very much mistaken!) `expect` doesn't return anything, so I guess I'm looking to modify these particular functions something similar tothe following jasmine-esque pseudo code (not intended as actual JS!)

`bailOnFail = true
expect (something).ToEqual(importantValue);
bailOnFail = false`

or alternatively

`if (something !== importantValue){
     fail ("Oh dear, it's all gone horribly wrong");
     exitSpec
}`

(As an aside, is there some sort of `pass` equivalent to the `fail` statement to add "arbitrary" passes to the results??!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Promise.reject();

```
if (something !== importantValue){
     Promise.reject("Oh dear, it's all gone horribly wrong");
}
```